# How to use an array formula in order to add up values under conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

is there any way I can sum up values indicated by column F (2) in one cell without adding additional column. I am pretty sure that I need to use an array formula, but I don't know how to do it. Database I am working on is huge so it needs to be automatic.

In this data sample the answer would be 19.

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: I really don't understand what you're going for here. What cells were added to get the total of 19? It sounds like [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) or [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) might help but we need clarity on what you want, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT($A$1:$E$1,1)=$F$2:$F$6)*A2:E6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **SUM** of **SUMIFs**:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(F:F,"a",A:A),SUMIF(F:F,"b",B:B),SUMIF(F:F,"c",C:C),,SUMIF(F:F,"d",D:D),,SUMIF(F:F,"e",E:E))
```